# merging nested lists and map in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hashmap

I have following list of maps, how can I get values inside map out and merge them as a new list

Example:

```
x = [ { "key1" => [{"K1" =>"123", "K2" =>"123"}] }, 
      { "key1" => [{"K3" =>"23", "K4" =>"32"}] }, 
      { "key1" => [{"K5" =>"34", "K6" =>"23"}] }]
```

What I want is:

```
[{"K1" =>"123", "K2" =>"123"}, 
{"K3" =>"23", "K4" =>"32"},
{"K5" =>"34", "K6" =>"23"}]
```

Comment: Try `x.map(&:values).flatten`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
x = [ { "key1" => [{"K1" =>"123", "K2" =>"123"}] }, 
  { "key1" => [{"K3" =>"23", "K4" =>"32"}] }, 
  { "key1" => [{"K5" =>"34", "K6" =>"23"}] }]

y = x.map{|h| h.map{|i,j| j} }.flatten
print(y)
```

This prints the below

```
[{"K1"=>"123", "K2"=>"123"}, {"K3"=>"23", "K4"=>"32"}, {"K5"=>"34", "K6"=>"23"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x.flat_map(&:entries).group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.map(&:last)]}
```

as:

```
> x = [ { "key1" => [{"K1" =>"123", "K2" =>"123"}] },
        { "key1" => [{"K3" =>"23", "K4" =>"32"}] },
        { "key1" => [{"K5" =>"34", "K6" =>"23"}] }]

> x.flat_map(&:entries).group_by(&:first).map{|k,v| Hash[k, v.map(&:last)]}
=> [{"key1"=>[[{"K1"=>"123", "K2"=>"123"}], [{"K3"=>"23", "K4"=>"32"}], [{"K5"=>"34", "K6"=>"23"}]]}]
```

I hope that helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as below,

```
x.map { |z| z.values[0][0] }
# => [{"K1"=>"123", "K2"=>"123"}, {"K3"=>"23", "K4"=>"32"}, {"K5"=>"34", "K6"=>"23"}]
```